# libsndfile Windows 7

Tags: c, dll

I'm trying to compile a program in C on a Windows 7 machine using MinGW.  Now I have to admit I don't have a lot of C experience to begin with and this is compounded by not being a very adept Windows user.

The program came with a make file, but it is getting stuck because I get the error:

> cannot find -lsndfile

I found that sndfile is a sound library for reading .wav files and the like.  I downloaded the library from http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile and ran the setup executable it comes with.  This put some header files and other junk in the Programs folder on C drive.

I copied the header files into the include folder under the MinGW directory, which reduced a lot of earlier errors down to one you see above.  I think I need to put a .dll file somewhere, but not sure where.

I can provide more detail if needed, since I'm not quite sure where the problem lies.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Libraries go to /usr/lib on POSIX (helpful if you use MinGW or Cygwin).

Comment: So the library came with a lib directory.  Inside there is a .def file and a .lib file.  But, inside the MinGW/lib directory, all I see are .a files and .o files.  Should I put the .def files and .lib files in with these?

Comment: .lib files have the same purpose as .a files, so probably yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the linkable library files (either .a, .lib or .dll) along with the other ones (which come by default with MinGW).

Comment: BTW I had to change the .lib extension to .a to compile.  The program is running so I guess that was OK.

Comment: @dvreed77 That's OK - .lib and .a are both static libraries, just VC++ names them .lib and GCC calls them .a.