# libsndfile Windows 8

Tags: c, dll

I wrote a little programm using libsndfile. I got it running on os x and linux. Last step would be windows.

I'm trying to compile using mingw. I downloaded the libsndfile installer from http://mega-nerd.com. After reading [libsndfile Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904357/libsndfile-windows-7) I placed the headder file in mingw's include folder which solved the first obvious error.

After that I tried everything mentioned in the other post: moved the .dll to mingw's bin folder, moved the .lib-, .def-files to the lib folder, thried it with renaming the .lib to .a. As a last triy I created /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib inside the mingw folder and copied everything there too.

The errors I are of the following type for different functions sf_*:

```
undefined reference to `sf_open'
```

So I figure that even after all the copying and renaming somehow the library is not found. Is there something else I can try?

Thanks.

---

Yes a very similar question already exists. But I didn't like posting another question as an answer and I have not enough reputation to write a commment to ask for details on solving this problem, so I opend another question. I hope it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

If the library wasn't found, you'd get an error saying that and `ld` would just die. Instead what you're getting are undefined references to libsnd functions -- ie, you never linked the library in the first place.

Comment: OK, I missed the -lsndfile but after adding it I get: ../ld.exe: cannot find -lsndfile
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

So I am where I thought I was before? Trying to put my lib in the right place.

Comment: Use `-L` to set a link-time lib folder.